# Correlation based feature selection(CFS) tool

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, feature-selection

Is there any tool or script that was implemented for correlation based feature selection? My feature vector data is in a large-scaled data file, so if I use tools like Weka for feature selection, I don't get any result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `findCorrelation` from R caret to achieve this, which selects the optimal subset of features to minimize their inter-feature correlation below a specified threshold. You will have to try out if this still works for your data (it will also run into problems with very huge dataset I assume):

```
# original correlation
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cor(mtcars), type = 'lower')
```

[image: Original correlation]

```
# finding optimal feature subset (as features to be removed)
library(caret)
toRemove <- findCorrelation(cor(mtcars), cutoff = 0.7)

# remaining correlation
corrplot(cor(mtcars[,-toRemove]), type = 'lower')
```

[image: Remaining correlation]

Answer (score -1):

You can try R packages that have built-in functions for feature selection. Some of them have `caret` package; also consider trying functions that calculate *variance inflation factor* for each variable.