# Check multicollinearity for $p > n$ data

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

To check the multicollinearity, the method I know is to use `vif` in `car` library. To use `vif`, we first have to fit a model. However, the data is $p > n$. We cannot fit a linear regression model with OLS. Then we try to fit in LASSO but all coefficients are 0. Hence, I cannot check the multicollinearity.

Is there a way to check multicollinearity without a model? For example, correlation matrix. But what if $x1 = x2 + x3$?

I have read this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221231/check-multicollinearity-before-regression-in-r) . I am not clear how does PCA detect (rather than handling) multicollinearity.

Comment: Which is it?  Your title says $p\gt n$ but you assert "the data is $p\lt n$." Regardless, it sounds like you know your data are multicollinear, so what does it mean to "check" it?  What does it mean to "handle" it?

Comment: I subjectively believe there is multicollinearity issue. I need a object method to see if there is such issue. By handle, I mean methods that would mitigate the issue. For example, deleting a variable. It seems I need to take English class along with statistics classes.

Comment: $p>n$ data is always multicolinear, no?

Comment: You cannot.  @Firebug is correct: $p \gt n$ implies collinearity, period.

Comment: When you say "check" are you searching for a way to find out which variables are responsible, perhaps in combination?

Comment: Please advise me which word do you guys use to describe the EXISTENCE  of a problem. Do you use "detect"? I don't want to know who is responsible at this stage. After we confirm the EXISTENCE, then we will be interested in who is responsible.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented (and @whuber ratified), $n<p$ data is always multicolinear. The reason is simply the rank deficiency that results in the linear dependency across variables, *i.e.* you end with an under-determined system. Just like is explained in [Why $p > n$ implies multicollinearity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241526/why-p-n-implies-multicollinearity).

The determinant of the covariance matrix is also an indication of multicollinearity: if it's equal to $0$ at least one eigenvalue is therefore $0$ which implies a linear dependence between variables.